# Finding the number of edges of a triangulation of a polygon on n vertices

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am faced with the following question:

A triangulation of an n-gon is a plane graph whose infinite face boundary is a convex n-gon and all of whose other faces are triangles. How many edges does a triangulation of an n-gon have?

I have looked up pictures and understand what a triangulation of an n-gon is. I noticed that the number of edges inside the polygon is equal to the number of triangles minus 1.

Can someone help me understand how to formulate the total number of edges? (This is my first undergraduate class in graph theory, so I am looking for a simple explanation.) Thanks so much!!

Comment: Try drawing pictures for $n = 3,4,5,6$ and see how many internal edges you have to have in each case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got the total number of edges to be 2(n-2)+1-- counting 3 edges for the first triangle, and 2 edges for each of the remaining triangles, with the maximum number of triangles being n-2. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. You can  post an answer to your own question now and then accept your answer, so the question doesn't remain in the unanswered queue.